# Resize facebook login Button

Tags: javascript

I am using facebook login button for my practice web site.

But I have a problem. There's a div tag I use for facebook login. I can fix the `width px` but I want to use it for react type in web.

I want to change `max-width` to `735px`, how can I do it?

Thanks

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false"
  data-height="100px" data-auto-logout-link="false" 
  data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>
```

Comment: ignore the data-height="100px" plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file, you can create a new class and apply it to your div. For example, in your file you could have

```
.login-reduced-width {
    max-width: 735px;
}
```

and then your div would look like

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false"
  data-height="100px" data-auto-logout-link="false" 
  data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could inline the CSS (this is generally not recommended, but it works):

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" 
  data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false"
  data-height="100px" data-auto-logout-link="false" 
  data-use-continue-as="false"
  style="max-width: 735px;">
</div>
```